# Ndk-bundle linking cxx failed with clang++ (structure core)

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I will try to explain my problem.
For two days I have been struggling with errors popping up during the process of building an android application.
I need to make an Android project for the Structure Core device, the manufacturer has put on his website a sample program and environment for which the scanner works, which I have uploaded to my cloud:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoHG6AtGqj2_g0eyFYMyh2uUNJUQ?e=aBpG1T

It's all about the build process itself which will allow me to open this project in Android Studio.

[image]

I do everything as in the instructions, but after executing the instructions, I get such an error and I have no idea what caused it. After installing ndk-bundle via SDK Manager, I had an ndk folder in AppData / Local / Android / Sdk, and the console asked for the ndk-bundle folder, so I just changed the name, I don't know if it was a problem, although I didn't find another solution.

[image]

At the moment I am working on a Windows generated environment and works good but i have to get an acces to Android App.
Ask if you could try to compile it on your own and possibly send me your ndk-bundle file or tell me what's wrong here.
Stucture Core notes that it is best to use ndk 21.01 and jdk11.
I tried to do this with a lot variation of java version.

Comment: [link] https://forums.structure.io/uploads/short-url/osnCYlTedheOA4zhmoHsIIr8ki7.pdf
Link to working build

Comment: To begin with I would suggest that you don't use any paths that contain spaces. Not for the NDK itself, and not for your code.

Comment: @mar97 The link you have given refers to the log.pdf only. Is there any chance that a working build is still available somewhere?